# Error Trying to Save from Excel to Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am trying to save an Excel 2010 file to a Sahrepoint 2010 document library but keep getting the error:

"You can't open this location using this program.  Please try a different location"

Googling this suggests enabling "Desktop Experience" on the server which I have done.  All Excel services are activated.

Has anyone come across this and been able to resolve successfully?  I am wondering if this is more security related but the security set-up looks fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are potentially a couple of things that could solve this problem depending on your set-up.

You are right that a lot of internet advice is to enable desktop experience, but if you are not running on the server or if you have already done this then one of the suggestions below could help.

This is only for dev environments however.

1. If you are running on the server and trying to use your app as admin then configuring IE ESC to turn off enhanced security for Admins should help
2. If you are running off server and have the issue and do not want to turn off IE ESC (on the server) for users then you need to enable a mechanism to allow auto-logon, either through integrated security (i.e. you are part of the domain), accessing through an anon web-site port on your SharePoint app (set-up anon web access in SharePoint) or set up and store a WebDav link and use that as the open/save URL.

My (unconfirmed) theory is that there is some auto-login going on in the background that hinders a streamlined office integration.  Most of the time, SharePoint will be set up with Kerberos (not NTLM) or be in anon mode so enabling desktop experience if running on the server will be the best first step to try.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the full path to the file is too long.

I had this problem with a PowerPoint presentation. The full path to the file was over 275 characters. When I shortened the file name to bring the full path under 250 characters, I was able to open the file normally.